# How do I merge a column from Dataframe (B) into Dataframe (A) but have column (Y) organised by the values in another column in Dataframe (A)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes containing data from the same group of 32 subjects. Dataframe (B) has the results of a test ordered by subject number (1-32). I would like to move this data into Dataframe (A) where the rest of my data is **and** have subject data from (B) link to the corresponding data in (A). Both dataframes have a shared column named (SID) corresponding to the same person. I want to move the **Score** column from dataframe (B) to (A). How would I do this?

Have in (B):

**SID** 1, 2, 3, 4...
**Score** 27, 39, 19, 38...

Have in (A):

**SID** 1, 2, 3, 4...
**Gender** M, F, F, M...

Want in (A):

**SID** 1, 2, 3, 4...
**Gender** M, F, F, M...
**Score** 27, 39, 19, 38...

I really would like to have presented this in a better format, sorry about that!

Comment: It does, and in so much detail. I am very new to Rstudio, and so my very limited terminology when searching for possible answers in the previous questions search-bar is likely what is making it so that I don't find something which has been answered. Thank you for your link, there's a lot of information to digest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want some sort of join (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html). I'll answer with `dplyr::full_join`:

```
## Create data frames
A = data.frame(
  SID   = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  score = c(27, 39, 19, 38)
  )

B = data.frame(
  SID    = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  gender = c("M", "F", "F", "M") 
  )

library(dplyr)

C = full_join(A, B, by = "SID")
C
#   SID score gender
# 1   1    27      M
# 2   2    39      F
# 3   3    19      F
# 4   4    38      M
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and example, . I hope you have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a merge task. As @NelsonGon suggested check that post and next time add data in order to reproduce your issue:

```
#Data
A <- data.frame(SID=1:4,Gender=c('M','F','F','M'),stringsAsFactors = F)
B <- data.frame(SID=1:4,Score=c(27,39,19,18))
#Merge
C <- merge(A,B,by = 'SID')

  SID Gender Score
1   1      M    27
2   2      F    39
3   3      F    19
4   4      M    18
```

Comment: I'll find out how to add data to a question before I post next time. I don't yet know how that's done. But thank you for your comment, solution, and recommendation :)

Comment: @HarryCaulton Great! Next time you can use `dput(yourdata)` or `dput(head(yourdata,20))` and paste the output in the question :)